# Retrieving user photos from facebook to android

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, photos

I wanted to know if there is a way to retrieve all user's pictures from his facebook and show them in a imageview like intent?

Thanks!

Comment: As your question tag implies, you can use the Facebook graph API to get the images, then you can do whatever you want with them.

Comment: Is there a way to get ALL the user's photos?

Comment: @JaviDorfsman You need to iterate through albums.